# Power Mock to mock static constructor failed

Tags: android, powermockito

I am using power mock to create and initialize object for static constructor

```
PowerMockito.when(RequestHandler.getInstance(coordinatorLayout,getSystemContext(‌​))).thenReturn(handler);
```

but on running the test I obtained:

> Unable to mock the construction of the RequestHandler object
>   cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException

```
 public RequestHandler(){
       this.client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    }

    public static RequestHandler getInstance(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,Context context){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new RequestHandler();
        }
        instance.coordinatorLayout = coordinatorLayout;
        instance.context=context;
        notificationProvider=new NotificationProvider(coordinatorLayout);
        instance.myUserSessionManager=new MyUserSessionManager(context);
        return instance;
    }
```

`

Comment: did you use `@PrePrepareForTest` and `mockStatic`?

Comment: `PowerMockito.when(RequestHandler.getInstance` this syntax is AFAIK incorrect, please read the doc